# Оружие смотрит ниже курсора - unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]я разрабатываю игру с видом сверху. Решил сделать пушку, которая будет смотреть прямо на курсор. У меня получилось, но пушка смотрит немного ниже.
На фотографии я отметил две точки - синию и красную. Красная точка - там где находится курсор, синяя - там где он должен находится, при данном развороте пушки. 
Вот как я делал ротацию.

```
void Update()
    {
        var dir = Input.mousePosition - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        ShotGun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
}
```

Comment: А что за магическая константа ` + 15` ? Куда смотрит пушка при угле = 0 ?(должна, по идее горизонтально вправо)  По картинке на глаз видно, что перекос угла на `90 градусов`, Может попробовать просто отнять 90 от `angle` - будет еще одна магическая константа :-)

Comment: покажите иерархию объектов пушки, не повернут ли спрайт изначально?